Spacy CoReference resolution in version 3.7
While following some documentation from spaCy to use the experimental Coreference Resolver (https://spacy.io/api/coref), I could make it work with the code below in spaCy 3.4.0.
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_coreference_web_trf")
text = "Philip plays the bass because he loves it"
doc = nlp(text)
print(doc.spans)

Unfortunately the same code, does not work in version 3.7.6 (latest as in 2024 Sept 26). For many reasons, the first is that there is no compatible model with 3.7.*. And I could not find other way to use it.
Any hints in how to use Coref resolution with the latest spaCy version?
